# Convert mp3 to ogg with Java and no external libraries

Tags: java, audio, mp3, ogg

I'm very limited on libraries I can use and I need to convert an mp3 to an ogg easily. This is using File classes because my code references with Files.
Is there a built in way I can do this with API? I tried renaming because it works for some programs but the specific reader I'm using can't decode renamed mp3s.

Comment: You will have to do a byte per byte conversion of the MP3 format to the OGG format. You would need to understand exactly an MP3 file looks it's layout and structure. The same for OGG.Not trivial not easy to do without library.

Comment: See this [SE Post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/20084/converting-audio-to-different-file-formats).